# How to take address input from user from html form, find coordinates and show it on a map? (using Mapbox)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

So I am trying to take input from user from a html form and show that location on a mapbox map.

My brief html code for form

```
<body>
   <div >
      <form>
         <input placeholder="Address" >
         <button >Search</button>
      </form>
   </div>
   <script src="input.js"></script>
</body>
```

My input.js ,its in the same folder

```
const address= document.querySelector('form');
const search = document.querySelector('input');

const geocode = (address, callback) => {
    const url = 'https://api.mapbox.com/geocoding/v5/mapbox.places/' + address + '.json?access_token=xxxxxxxxx&limit=1'

    request({ url: url, json: true }, (error, response) => {
        if (error) {
            callback('Unable to connect to location services!', undefined)
        } else if (response.body.features.length === 0) {
            callback('Unable to find location. Try another search.', undefined)
        } else {
            callback(undefined, {
                latitude: response.body.features[0].center[0],
                longitude: response.body.features[0].center[1],
            })
        }
    })
}

address.addEventListener('submit', (e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    const location = search.value;
    console.log(location); 
    geocode(location);
})
```

I have console logged `location` and seen that the `eventListener` works but after inserting the geocode function it doesn't work returns this error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: request is not defined
    at geocode (input.js:11)
    at HTMLFormElement.<anonymous> (input.js:31)
```

The 11th line is

```
 request({ url: url, json: true }, (error, response) => {
```

31st is

```
geocode(location)
```

After this works I want to export the latitude and longitude to another file where plotting of map is done. How do i export these two values?

Comment: It can't find the request function, are you pulling in your request library correctly?

Comment: const request = require('request')
I am doing it like this but then it gives me error of request is defined. And I have done the following things for this.

Comment: 1) npm install requirejs 2) include the minified version of require js and store it in the same directory in the name reqire.js

Comment: Even then it keeps me same error. What should I do?